# Simply Scheme Chapter 09. Lambda. Any more Lambda exercises?

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, lisp, scheme

Greets,

Reading [Simply Scheme](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~bh/ss-toc2.html) [Chapter 09](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~bh/ssch9/lambda.html) and from what I can see, Lambda seems important. I'd like to practice it to the bone so I'm looking for beginner exercises (preferably non recursive) vis à vis [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) that focus on lambda. Let inclusive is bonus. Got any resources?

Online, I found [this](http://people.cs.aau.dk/~normark/prog3-03/html/notes/fu-intr-1-lambda-expr-note-exercise-1.html) and references to Simply Scheme. I understand there are good [books](http://programming-musings.org/2007/01/31/a-scheme-bookshelf/), but I'm really just looking for exercises.

Many Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about learning about a language or language feature.  Try programmers.SE, I think this question would be appropriate there.

Answer (score 5):

If you're learning Scheme, you have to understand recursion from the very start. I'd suggest [The Little Schemer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262560992) for this, and for your question, take a look at Chapter 8: *Lambda the Ultimate* - there you'll find plenty of exercises (in Q&A format) dealing with `lambda`. Its follow-up, titled [The Seasoned Schemer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/026256100X), is also a fantastic book with chapters and exercises explaining `let`.

Another beginner's level book, great for teaching yourself Scheme, would be [How to Design Programs](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/). And finally, for a more advanced book with more math-flavored exercises, you can't miss [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html), it will change forever the way you think about programming. Of course, all of the books mentioned will have exercises related to `lambda` ... among many other subjects.

Comment: Those are good resources, but my immediate need is practice. Do you know anywhere I can find exercises?

Comment: Oh, I see. Now I get it. Was really hoping for a list of exercises, but it doesn't get more definitive than this. +1 for [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html).

Comment: @usernvk I updated my answer listing a couple more books. Have fun!

Comment: Awesome post, will look into the Little Schemer. Thanks for the chapter reference.